# How do you get the red orbs in trial?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

How do you get the red orbs in trial?

Comment: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M62vdaI6bLo), the author provides some tips in the comments - are any of them useful? Is this relevant?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. What are red orbs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to beat developpers' time, which are completely crazy times harder to get than diamond times.

[Here is a video of all Pearl Times minus Dark World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo97NzwvjKQ)

[Here are all the times](http://towerfall.wikidot.com/trials)

If you don't want to click, here are the times needed for Pearl Times (in seconds):

**Sacred Ground:** 1.700, 2.300 and 2.400

**Twilight Spire** 1.300, 1.200 and 2.200

**Backfire** 2.400, 1.900 and 3.000

**Flight** 2.100, 4.100 and 2.600

**Mirage** 2.400, 2.500 and 3.300

**Thornwood** 3.000, 3.000 and 3.800

**Frostfang Keep** 2.600, 2.900 and 3.000

**King's Court** 2.300, 3.500 and 2.600

**Sunken City** 2.700, 4.100 and 3.600

**Moonstone** 2.800, 2.600 and 2.300

**TowerForge** 1.000, 2.300 and 1.800

**Ascension** 4.100, 3.300 and 4.100

**The Amaranth** 1.850, 2.500 and 2.250

**Dreadwood** 1.750, 1.950 and 3.500

**Darkfang** 2.000, 2.550 and 2.200

**Cataclysm** 1.700, 2.200 and 2.350